# JQuery .get() only passing first two data parameters in url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a $.get() call to a PHP page that takes 4 GET parameters. For some reason, despite giving the $.get() call all 4, it only passes the first two. When I look at the dev console in chrome, it shows the URL that gets called, and it only passes action and dbname. Heres the code:

```
$.get('util/util.php', { action: 'start', dbname: db, url: starturl, crawldepth: depth }, function(data) {
        if (data == 'true') {
            status = 1;
            $('#0').append(starturl + "<ul></ul>");
            $('#gobutton').hide();
            $('#loading').show("slow");
            while(status == 1) {
                setTimeout("update()",10000);

            }
        } else {
            show_error("Form data incomplete!");
        }
    });
```

and heres the URL that I see in the developer console:

`http://localhost/pci/util/util.php?action=start&dbname=1hkxorr9ve1kuap2.db`

** EDIT **
I have been informed that I need to encode the URL that I am trying to pass through the header. How would I go about encoding it in javascript, and decoding it in php?

Comment: Are you sure that `starturl` and `depth` are defined? Also you have to encode the URL.

Comment: yes they are defined. How do i encode the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that the `starturl` and `depth` variables are defined? A simple `alert()` before the $.get() will be enough to check.

In regards to your edit, you can encode strings in JavaScript with the `encodeURIComponent` function. And decode it back again in the PHP with `urldecode`. They both take one string argument.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will need to check whether your input strings are properly quoted. Internally jQuery will build the paramter string out of the parameter map you specified using its `param()` method. This method will construct an object of the keys and values, which will likely not be parseable if you quoted your keys and values incorrectly.

@ Felix Kling: jQuery automatically encodes keys and values of the parameter string with encodeURIComponent.